# Stripe Card Element Input Has A Black Input In Multi-Step Form

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am making a multi-part form and I am using stripe to collect the card information. However, whenever I switch from one part to another and switch back to the card element stripe provides there is a black background on my input. Does anyone know the issue?

I've tried messing with the card options stripe provides and thought maybe there was some styling stripe provides for empty or invalid cards but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

[image: Black Input Here]

```
import classes from "./Form.module.css"
import Button from "../UI/Button"
import Heading1 from "../UI/Heading1"
import Input from "./Input"
import { Transition } from "react-transition-group"
import useInput from "../../hooks/useInput"
import validator from "validator"
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import ButtonDisabled from "../UI/ButtonDisabled"
import Select from "./Select"
import { CardElement } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"


const CARD_OPTIONS = {
    iconStyle: "solid",
    hidePostalCode: true,
    classes: {
        focus: classes.cardContainerFocus,
    },
    style: {
        base: {
            iconColor: "#fe019a",
            color: "#f1a6d3",
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            fontWeight: 500,
            fontFamily: "Roboto, Open Sans, Segoe UI, sans-serif",
            fontSize: "16px",
        },
        invalid: {
            iconColor: "red",
            color: "red",
        },
    },
}

const FormPayment = (props) => {

    const [formIsValid, setFormIsValid] = useState(false)

    const currencyRef = useRef('')

    const {
        value: amountValue,
        error: amountError,
        errorMessage: amountErrorM,
        touched: amountTouched,
        onChangeHandler: amountOnChange,
        onBlurHandler: amountOnBlur,
    } = useInput('Enter A Valid Amount', (value) => validator.isNumeric(value.trim()))
    
    const {
        value: cardNameValue,
        error: cardNameError,
        errorMessage: cardNameErrorM,
        touched: cardNameTouched,
        onChangeHandler: cardNameOnChange,
        onBlurHandler: cardNameOnBlur,
    } = useInput("Empty Name", (value) => !validator.isEmpty(value.trim()))

    useEffect(() => {
        const formHasError = (
            amountError ||
            cardNameError
        )

        const formIsFilled =
            !!(amountValue &&
            cardNameValue)

        if(!formHasError && formIsFilled) {
            setFormIsValid(true)
        } else {
            setFormIsValid(false)
        }

    }, [
        amountError,
        cardNameError,
        amountValue,
        cardNameValue,
    ])

    const onSubmitHandler = () => {
        props.incrementCount()
        props.updateInfo({
            Currency: currencyRef.current.value,
            Amount: amountValue,
            CardName: cardNameValue,
        })
    }
    return (
        <Transition in={props.in} mountOnEnter={false} unmountOnExit timeout={200}>
            {(state) => (
                <div
                    className={`${classes.formContainer}
                     ${state === "exiting" && classes.exiting}
                     ${state === "entering" && classes.entering}
                        `}
                >
                    <Heading1 className={classes.title}>Payment Info</Heading1>
                    <div className={classes.container}>
                        <Select
                            className={classes.shrinkSmall}
                            ref={currencyRef}
                            name="Currency"
                            data={["CAD", "USD", "GBP"]}
                            ></Select>
                        <Input
                            value={amountValue}
                            onBlur={amountOnBlur}
                            onChange={amountOnChange}
                            error={amountError}
                            errorMessage={amountErrorM}
                            touched={amountTouched}
                            name="Amount"
                            ></Input>
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes.container}>
                        <Input
                            value={cardNameValue}
                            onBlur={cardNameOnBlur}
                            onChange={cardNameOnChange}
                            error={cardNameError}
                            errorMessage={cardNameErrorM}
                            touched={cardNameTouched}
                            name="Card Holder Name"
                        ></Input>
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes.cardContainer}>
                        <CardElement options={CARD_OPTIONS}></CardElement>
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes.splitContainer}>
                        <Button onClick={props.decrementCount}>{"<"} Back</Button>
                        {formIsValid ? (
                            <Button onClick={onSubmitHandler}>Next {">"}</Button>
                        ) : (
                            <ButtonDisabled>Next {">"}</ButtonDisabled>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </Transition>
    )
}

export default FormPayment
```

Comment: it is very hard to reproduce, for, youd have to have a working stripe setup. how about you try the browser-internal debugger? click on the element with the black background and inspect where the rule is coming from. and then you can add a rule that replaces the rule annoying you. gl.

Comment: would you be able to provide a link to a working page that reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering around it about, it seems to be one of my chrome extensions acting funny, after going into incognito the problem fixed itself.

Comment: This isn't caused by extensions. It's a chrome visual bug caused by transitions. Disable and enable the bottom transition when the bug happens. Inspect the card number element itself.
https://i.imgur.com/uaHWPDT.png